# How to wrap two posts in ajax-load-more Wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I am writing blog for Wordpress using Bootstrap grid. My first post is sticky, 100% width of column. Next posts should be placed undearneath it in two columns.
Every two posts are wrapped in div with .row class to keep them in line. I've done this and it worked perfectly.

```
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="top-news">
        // sticky post
    </div>

    <div class="next-news-grid">
        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php if(is_sticky()) continue; ?>
            <?php if( $wp_query->current_post%2 != 0 ) echo "\n".'<div class="row">'."\n"; ?>
            <div class="col-md-6 next-news">
                <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('next-  news-thumbnail'); ?></a>
                <?php } ?>
                <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h4>
                <hr>
                <?php the_content( "read more" ); ?>
            </div>
            <?php if( $wp_query->current_post%2 != 1 || $wp_query->current_post == $wp_query->post_count-1 ) echo '</div> <!--/.row-->'."\n"; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

But I want to use [ajax-load-more plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-load-more/) to automatically load posts on the same page after button is clicked. Unfortunately it won't wrap my posts in .row class anymore.
I copied my while loop into repeater template in plugin settings but it seems like it's ignoring the if statement parts with div appending. Therefore it looks ugly when one post is longer and is pushing another to the right AND another down making huge gaps between them.
So how can I wrap every two posts in div.row container with this plugin? Or can I use something else to achieve infinite loading with button?